# Mirror gitlab repo to SVN

Tags: git, gitlab, git-svn, gitlab-ci

I have gitlab repository that I want to mirror it to a (read-only) SVN using gitlab continuous integration. Every time I create a tag, I want gitlab CI to run a script to commit the master branch to SVN.
I am pretty familiar um gitlab CI, but so much with git-svn tool.

Is there a easy way to achieve that?

Comment: You need to install `gitlab-runner` on your SVN machine and register it to GitLab. Then you need to create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` in your Git repository and have it execute a script to do the mirror operation. You'll want to verify in your CI settings for the project that the Runner is registered and that CI is turned on.

Comment: (1) https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/ (2)
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html

Comment: Do you need each individual commit on the SVN server, or only the tagged snapshots?

Comment: @Vampire,   I need only tagged snapshots...  The gitlab CI configuration is already done: the runner, stages, jobs, etc...   The only part missing is the gitsvn script. I am not sure on how to sync git ->svn..

Comment: Forget `git-svn`, just `svn delete` everything, copy over your workspace, `svn add everything and commit.

Comment: ok, thanks..  well thought